# Версия SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Есть ли различия, с какой версии начинать изучение SQL Server 2005 или 2008? Почитав комментарии, что особых различий между ними нету. Многие советуют книгу Роберта Вийеры. Но в интернете она есть только по 2005 SQL. На самом деле нету разницы с какой версии начинать знакомство с SQL Server?

Comment: В названиях серверов Вы забыли буквы MS. Без них вопрос несколько расплывчатым получается.

Answer (score 1):

Главное начать. :-)
Все, что работает под 2005, будет работать и под 2008.

Впрочем, если подождать немного, у вас появится еще один вариант - 2012. :-)

Comment: Ну гарантий полной совместимости снизу вверх я бы за майкрософт не давал.

Comment: На sql-ex.ru последовательно менялось 2000-->2005-->2008R2. И я не припомню проблем совместимости.

Comment: "Не было" -- не означает "не будет".

Comment: Я не оцениваю вероятность, а говорю о существующих версиях, которые уже не изменятся.

Comment: Проблемы, насколько я помню, у меня были с типами данных в INFORMATION_SCHEMA. В какой-то версии точность колонок с фиксированной точкой задавалась целым, в другой версии - коротким целым.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с SQL, с языка запросов для начала. Почувствуйте DML и DDL. Потом изучите разновидности по желанию Tr-SQL, PL-SQL, PG-SQL. А выбрав один или несколько пройдитесь по стандартам и версиям каждой из них.